# Description Resource Path Location TypeMissing include: test.xsl

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, xslt, resources

I have top.xsl file which includes test.xsl as below:

The top.xsl is processed at run time to render a webpage.

the test.xsl is found in another jar (test.jar) at run time.

My eclipse have dependency on test.jar.

how to get rid of below error in the eclipse:

Description Resource Path Location TypeMissing include: test.xsl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The static content in jar files (**.xml* files certainly is for instance) is not visible to classes accessing it from different jar or Eclipse project without extracting the jar. However, the classes situated in the *test.jar* should have access to it.

You may consider creating the *"home dir"* for your app, if there are more resources, and place the configuration, or other content, there during the installation or application's first run.

Or if you don't care about clean solution and all you need is to get this work, you can simply extract the XSLT file from jar and access it by using absolute path.

Hope, it helped.